# Has anyone used the Import Sceneform Asset plug-in?

Tags: android, plugins, augmented-reality, arcore

Has anyone used the Import Sceneform Asset plug-in? I keep using it and pressing Finish, but nothing happens. As far as I know, there should be a sfb file or sfa file in the specified folder. I don't know if I'm using it wrong or if it's supposed to be like this. It says sfa file and sfb file are created from obj file, and it's written in the Dox that the sceneform.asset file is created on the gradle. Is it not possible in macos environment? If it's just a plug-in problem, is there a way to use 3D file other than this plug-in?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Android Studio are u using now?

For me, only Android Studio 3.5 worked with Sceneform Asset plug-in.

If you cannot find any solution, as a workaround, you can just transfer to Sceneform 1.16 and use gltf not sfb.

Go check this link of github ticket.
https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/1078